# Gmaps4rails Map fixed to top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, gmaps4rails

Hello guys and merry Xmas to all of you :)
I am currently using gmaps4rails to display a map with all my user locations. Now I'd like to fix it to the top directly under my fixed-top navbar. I've tried a lot of css code but still don't get the output I want. ( I am using twitter bootstrap)
Any ideas or code examples how to override the gmaps4rails css to fix it? Would be even nicer if the map is responsive too.
Thanks :)

Comment: There is no gmaps4rails css

Answer (score 0):

If your navbar is 50px:

```
<style type="text/css">
 html { height: 100% }
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding-top: 50px }
 #map { height: 100% }
</style>
```